# Why is »hat« used in this sentence instead of »ist«?

Tags: sentence-structure, sein-or-haben

The below paragraph comes from the article “[Die deutsche Heimat von Donald Trump.
„Drump babbelt nur“.](http://taz.de/Die-deutsche-Heimat-von-Donald-Trump/!5374809/)” in *taz.de*:

> Es gibt ein Dorf in Deutschland, da mag man Ketchup lieber als Geld.
>   Geld, sagt man da, was ist das schon? Aber Ketchup! In diesem Dorf
>   leben ungefähr zwölfhundert Menschen, es gibt eine Kirche, eine
>   Bäckerei, die bis mittags **auf hat**, und eine Metzgerei, das
>   „Saumagenparadies“. Es gibt um die zwanzig Gaststätten. Und die sind
>   abends immer voll. Es gibt eine schmale Straße, sie verästelt sich ein
>   wenig nach links und nach rechts, führt einen Hügel hinauf. Sie ist
>   gesäumt von bunten alten Häusern: die Deutsche Weinstraße. Noch lieber
>   als Ketch­up mag man hier Wein.

Why is *auf hat* used in the second sentence of the above paragraph? Should it not be *auf ist*? According to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=auf%20sein),

> to be open = auf sein

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/aufhaben) says:

> etw. geöffnet haben
>   Gegenwort zu zuhaben (...)
>   *Beispiele:*
>   das Fenster, die Tür aufhaben
>   wann haben am Sonnabend die Geschäfte auf?
>   den Mund, die Augen aufhaben

And, by the way, dict.cc does list *aufhaben*, either if you search that word directly, or if you search *to be open*.

http://www.dict.cc/?s=to+be+open

Comment: But if the use of "aufhaben" is intended, should not the word sequence be "hat auf" ("eine Bäckerei, die bis mittags hat auf")? Shouldn't prefix come at the end?

Comment: The bold text is in a relative sentence.

Comment: But should it not then be "aufhat" instead of "auf hat"?

Comment: So it seems. IM-unexperienced-O  it's colloquial enough, for you to ignore that it should be written together.

Answer (score 3):

Locations can actively **aufhaben** if there are opening hours.

> Die Kneipe hat erst morgen wieder auf.
>   Die Bibliothek hat nur bis zu Beginn der Schulferien auf. *etc*

**Aufhaben** usually refers to the opening hours. **Auf sein** generally refers to the actual status of the location. Same for *geöffnet*:

> Das Museum ist/hat am Sonntag auf.
>   Das Geschäft ist/hat bis mittags geöffnet.

In the example you gave, **aufhaben** feels more natural, because its a *general description* of a village and a bakery with *usual opening hours*.

> In diesem Dorf leben ungefähr zwölfhundert Menschen, es gibt eine
>   Kirche, eine Bäckerei, die bis mittags **auf hat**, und eine Metzgerei.

But, quite often, *aufhaben* und *auf sein* are used synonymously.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what I cannot: why is *auf hat* and not *aufhat*?

Comment: @ Kristina Yes, please, explain why it is "auf hat" and not "aufhat".

Comment: I suppose that it is due to the spelling reforms. Formerly: abhanden kommen / absein. New: abhandenkommen / ab sein. I think *auf haben* is pre-reform but I'm not sure of it.

Answer (score 2):

> please, explain why it is "auf hat" and not "aufhat"

Because in Germany, even journalists and copy editors sometimes – consciously or negligently – take liberties with the "official" spelling rules. Officially, it's `auf sein` and `aufhaben`, which doesn't make much logical sense, even though there may be a linguistic explanation lurking there somewhere (e.g. in the difference between transitive and non-transitive verb).

However, in my perspective, this is one of those tiny details that only worth obsessing over when you have the complete German grammar down cold. There are many more examples:

- `zugrunde legen` /correct/, `zu Grunde legen` /correct/ or `zugrundelegen` /wrong/
- `zusammenschreiben` /correct/, `zusammen schreiben` /wrong/
- `getrennt schreiben` /correct/, `getrenntschreiben` /wrong/

With regard to writing words separately or as a single word, the most important rule to know (and one which is ignored by many native speakers today) is that in German, as opposed to English, **compound nouns are written as one word** – without a space, and without a hyphen:

- `Premiumausstattung` /correct/, `Premium Ausstattung` /wrong/, `Premium-Ausstattung` /wrong, unless you consider the word very long and therefore difficult to read/
- `Scheinwerferreinigungssystem` /correct/, `Scheinwerfer-Reinigungssystem` /correct if you agree that this is a rather long compound/, `Scheinwerfer Reinigungssystem` /wrong/